# Pulling values from website using VBA but website values pulled from other sites

Tags: excel, vba, screen-scraping

I want to take the Canada CMB rate off of the greenbirchcapital.com website, however am running into trouble with VBA getting that value, seemingly due to the fact that the value is pulled from thefinancials.com. A variation of this code pulls the Canada bond numbers from the Gov. of Can. website fine, as (using the same logic) that is the source. Some help to edit this code would be much appreciated!

```
Sub ScrapeWebsiteTable()
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim tableElements As Object
    Dim table As Object
    Dim row As Object
    Dim cell As Object
    Dim rowNum As Long
    Dim colNum As Long
    Dim tableData As String

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ' Configure IE settings
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.navigate "https://greenbirchcapital.com/bond-yields/"

    ' Wait for IE to load the webpage
    Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    ' Get the table elements from the webpage
    Set tableElements = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")
    
    ' Check if any table elements are found
    If Not tableElements Is Nothing Then
            ' Access the table at the specified index
            Set table = tableElements(0)
            
            tableData = ""
            
            ' Loop through the rows and columns of the table
            For Each row In table.Rows
                For Each cell In row.Cells
                    ' Append the cell value to the tableData variable
                    tableData = tableData & cell.innerText & vbTab
                Next cell
                
                ' Append a new line character after each row
                tableData = tableData & vbNewLine
            Next row
            
            ' Display the extracted table data
            MsgBox tableData
        Else
            MsgBox "Table element not found."
        End If

    ' Close IE
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Please can you clarify 'running into trouble' ... what is the result you are getting ... does the code error (which error number and what error text, on what line) or does it produce the wrong output (in which case what is the output you get and what is the output you expected)?

Comment: @JohnM I get run time error 91 object variable or with block variable not set, on the For Each row In table.Rows line. But, if the table didnt exist wouldnt I get back one of my msgbox messages?

Comment: I am not very familiar with HTML but isn't it possible, that in a table there is no <tr> element?

Comment: I think the code was not written for the given url. But since each page was developed individually, a web scraping bot must also be developed individually for each page. There are several problems in the VBA code. At first, almost certainly a timing problem, because the data table is later loaded. The check whether tableElements is available will always be positive, because the `getElements...()` methods also create an empty node collection if no element was found. Here, `.length > 0` would have to be checked. The data is not in a table tag, it were div tags. IE should also no longer be used.

Comment: @Zwenn Yeah I am not very good at this... I had created it for the GoC website and it was able to return the value I wanted fine but then I tried to apply the same skeleton to the new site and thats when I came here.